# How far can a .xlsx file be simplified

Tags: php, xml, excel, file, format

I'm currently working on a `PHP` project and would like to provide (very basic) Excel export of a database table (only strings and numbers in cells, no formatting, etc.). I have read up on the various Excel file formats. I would like to *avoid including a library* to do this.

I have considered using the legacy [Microsoft Office XML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example) and it seems like the easiest solution. But Excel warns when I give the file an `.xls` extension instead of `.xml`. I don't want to generate `.xml` files though, as I can not guarantee that users of my project will know not to simply double click the files and be confused. I'll leave this as a final option.

Ideally, I'd like to generate a [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) (.xlsx, aka. Excel Workbook) file that current versions of Excel open without complaining. So I looked into the format and found it's a `zip`-compressed folder of `.xml` files.

[image: structure of a xlsx file]

I figured I'd just put the whole directory up on the server, write/replace `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`, zip it up again and output to the browser.
Sadly, the worksheet does not contain actual strings and numbers, but references all values from `sharedStrings.xml`.

I found this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18820405/3625228 but ideally, I'd like to get rid of whatever files I can to simplify the `.xlsx`.

I looked into `[Content_Types].xml`, where the dependencies are stored:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
    <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/xl/sharedStrings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
</Types>
```

**My question is:**

- is it possible to remove files from the `.xlsx` archive?
- What are the files that are absolutely needed for Excel to open without complaining?
- And is there a way or a trick to put the actual strings/values into `sheet1.xml` and skip `sharedStrings.xml` altogether?

*Disclaimer: Not looking for libraries and/or help using Microsoft Office XML (Excel 2003) format files*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write directly to the sheet1.xml ... I'm doing it like so: https://github.com/nimmneun/OneSheet
Maybe it gives you one or two ideas =)
I also don't use a theme file btw.

update:
In case you're still searching ... I discovered that you actually only need 5 files, just make sure your rels point to the proper files/filenames:

```
workbook.xml
worksheet.xml
[Content_Types].xml
_rels/.rels
_rels/workbook.xml.rels
```

For reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2007/05/29/simple-spreadsheetml-file-part-3-formatting/

I linked part-3 b/c it has links to part 1 & 2 =)

Comment: Wow, this solved the `sharedStrings.xml` problem for me. With your code I learned about inlineStr! `<c r="A1" t="inlineStr"><is><t>My inline string</t></is></c>`. Great! Maybe somebody else knows which files can be removed from the archive, but this already helped me a lot!